# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Have anyone experienced this?

> String or binary data would be truncated

Raised during `ALTER INDEX`; even in `CREATE TABLE`. I'm not having this problem in other databases. I may have reconfigured something as this is only a test database.

[image]

All I am seeing in the internet is regarding length of strings inserted by `INSERT` statement exceeds in the length of defined data type.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Check for triggers, and DDL triggers on the database.

The error message gives the name of what to look for: procedure **`DatabaseAudit`** line 47.